# Debian 9 disk filled overnight, and emptied next morning? How to track down the issue?

Tags: debian, diskmanagement

Here is a munin screenshot about it: [image: SSD raid filled and emptied]

It filled at around: 07/Nov/2017:19:41:03 
and emptied at: 08/Nov/2017:04:05:05.

The closest cronjob was at 04:05:50, a postfix & dovecot restart.

I know these from other services logs, the root drives were so full even logging stopped at that point.

I'm using debian 9, with the following services running:

[ + ]  acpid
 [ + ]  ajenti
 [ + ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ + ]  apache2
 [ + ]  atd
 [ + ]  avahi-daemon
 [ + ]  cron
 [ + ]  dbus
 [ + ]  dovecot
 [ + ]  fail2ban
 [ + ]  irqbalance
 [ + ]  kmod
 [ + ]  memcached
 [ + ]  minissdpd
 [ + ]  munin-node
 [ + ]  mysql
 [ + ]  networking
 [ + ]  ntp
 [ + ]  postfix
 [ + ]  procps
 [ + ]  rc.local
 [ + ]  rpcbind
 [ + ]  rsyslog
 [ + ]  smartmontools
 [ + ]  ssh
 [ + ]  stunnel4
 [ + ]  udev
 [ + ]  unattended-upgrades
 [ + ]  urandom

My question is, how could I track down what caused this strange disk fillup ( & emptying ) ? And if not, can i prevent it somehow?

Comment: Look in `/var/log/` and which program generates that lots of output.

Comment: Szia Ipor! 
**Well, it was auth.log and:**

`Nov  7 19:54:01 wwNov  8 04:06:01 www CRON[12546]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)`


**but this was the first from postfix:**
`[Tue Nov 07 19:41:03.716505 2017] [log_config:warn] [pid 30788] (28)No space left on device: [...]`

Comment: Look at the biggest logfile and search for a tons on duplicated lines in it.